# Formatting data on a lightning component without using lightningrecordform

Tags: lightning-aura-components, callout, data

So, I am currently working on a call out to another service outside of Salesforce. I have made the call out and am successfully returning data from the service outside Salesforce. So, my question is can I format this data to look more user friendly? I have been trying to use record lightning form, but since I am not calling on a Salesforce object I really can't use it. Currently I am using  `<lightning:formattedText>` to display my data, but I need something a little more visual pleasing. Any ideas?

Comment: Currently I am using <lightning:formattedText need something a little more visual pleasing then that. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the data structure that you are getting back from the external service? How would you like to visualize it?

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far and what expect?